# Quartz scheduler missing job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am adding a job to quartz scheduler. After that I call the attached debug print jobs function. It does not list the job. Is the function call to `getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()` maybe limited to return max. of 10 jobs?

```
public void scheduleManagementEmail(ManagementEmailConfig managementEmailConfig, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException
{
    logger.debug("Scheduling Management Email " + 
    managementEmailConfig.getManagementEmailConfigId());

    String jobKey = "SendManagementEmailJob_" +     
    managementEmailConfig.getManagementEmailConfigId();
    Class<? extends Job> jobClass = SendManagementEmailJob.class;
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(new JobKey(jobKey)).build();
    Trigger trigger = sendManagementEmailJob.getTriggerWithSchedule(managementEmailConfig);
    trigger.getJobDataMap().put("managementEmailConfigId", managementEmailConfig.getManagementEmailConfigId());
    if (!scheduler.checkExists(new JobKey(jobKey)))
    {
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
    debugPrintJobs();
}

public void debugPrintJobs() {
    try {
        logger.debug("Quartz Jobs");
        Scheduler s_scheduler = this.getJobScheduler();
        List<JobExecutionContext> currentJobs = s_scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
    for (JobExecutionContext jobCtx : currentJobs) {
        JobKey jobKey = jobCtx.getJobDetail().getKey();             
        JobDetail jobDetail = s_scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey);
        List<? extends Trigger> triggers = s_scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);

        Date nextFireTime = null;
        if (triggers.size() > 0)
        {
            nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime();
        }
        logger.debug("Name= "+ jobKey.getName() + " Group=" + jobKey.getGroup() + " NextFireTime=" + nextFireTime); 
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug("debugPrintJobs:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: 'I am adding a job to quartz scheduler.' Not in the code you show us.

Comment: Could you please improve the indention of your code? It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()` will return only the jobs that are running, not every scheduled job.
To get every scheduled job, you should do something like this:

```
    Scheduler scheduler = getScheduler();
    try {
        // All scheduled jobs
        for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
            for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
                JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey);
                final List<? extends Trigger> triggersOfJob = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
                // Do something with the info you just got
                // ...
            }
        }
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        log.error("Retrieving jobs", e);
    }
```